# Does my cat have a boyfriend?

Tags: cats, psychology, territory

So I just walked downstairs to find my black cat chilling out on the table with a ginger cat in the room, with no issues whatsoever. The cat is called Peter and owned by someone who lives nearby. This isn't the first time I've found Peter in my house, he's been lying on the sofa before as well as eating from the food in my house, when he did that I shouted "Shoo, Peter, shoo! Run while you can!" and he shot right out.

I'm a bit confused as to why Peter is coming into my house and my cat isn't showing hostility to him. I am now convinced that they are in deep love with each other. Luckily my cat is neutered. Maybe my cat is inviting Peter round to play or to eat breakfast with her, I have no idea, and I hope I can figure out if she's inviting Peter to our house.

In fact, lately Peter has been coming round every day.

I don't take very kindly to Peter because I don't know if he's coming in without my cat's permission or with my cat's permission. I don't care if he's in my house, I doubt he'll do much harm but I just want to know... why.... there's loads of other people who live near me who have cats who he could visit.

- Is my cat friends with Peter?
- Why is Peter visiting me?

I believe that my cat is going out with Peter. I'm not entirely sure, but I can just guess it...

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this can be seen as an answer, but here goes.

This happened in the mid 80s. My neutered male cat, Mons, did come home with a small female cat when I was a teen. I used to let my cat in by opening my window.

My cat refused to let me close the window. He made a lot of noise and called out loud. The female cat jumped inside through the open window and my male cat prevented me getting anywhere close to this cat. He hissed at me to let this female cat eat his food alone.

The two cats spent all their time together outside and only came inside to eat for a short time before they left again.

This happened every day for close to two months but one day the female cat was gone. I don't know where the cat went. Hopefully it did go home.

So yes it is possible for cats to fall badly madly in love, and I do think this time was the best time in my cat's life.

My male cat did not have a negative reaction when the female cat left and was straight back to his crazy self (my cat was not usually nice to other cats).

Comment: I have seen similar behavior. Cats can make friends with other new cats they meet. It surprises me when they do this given how territorial they tend to be.

Comment: i am glad to see other people have had similar experiences so that i dont apear to be compleatly insane.